# CakePHP does not use my models

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.4

I have got these two CakePHP V 2.4.5 models:

```
class Owner extends AppModel {
    public $name = 'Owner';
    public $hasMany = array('Car');
}
```

and

```
class Car extends AppModel {
    public $name = 'Car';
    public $belongsTo = array('Owner');
}
```

in my controller I wrote:

```
var $uses = array('Owner', 'Car');

public function test(){
    $data = array(
        'Owner' => array(
            'name' => 'Me'
        ),
        'Car' => array(
            array('color' => 'red'),
            array('color' => 'blue')
        )
    );
    $this->Owner->saveAssociated($data, array('deep' => true));
}
```

But CakePHP created the owner and forgets to create his cars:

```
1   BEGIN
2   INSERT INTO `test`.`owners` (`name`) VALUES ('Me')
3   COMMIT
```

This is what my ERM looks like:

[image: ERM]

Why does CakePHP not save the cars?

Comment: what's your dbms? Maybe your table doesn't support transactions. Try `saveAssociated($data, array('atomic' => false))` (you don't need the deep option because Owner id in direct association with Car)

Comment: I am using MySQL V 5.1.41 in the standard configuration that was shipped with Xampp for Windows.

Comment: and what kind of table? See my edit above.

Comment: I just handed a transaction into PhpMyAdmin, so I could verify that MySQL let's me insert multiple records in one transaction. There it worked. Using `atomic => false` indeed omitted the `BEGIN` and `COMMIT` statements, but there was still only the one statement left which inserted the owner. Do you need any more information?

Comment: I was just curious about the kind of storage engine you are using. But if you can make trasactions then I guess is InnoDB

Comment: I didn't know there were any differences of the storage engines. Strangely PhpMyAdmin performed my transaction although my tables are MyISAM. If it's true that MyISAM does not support transactions, then that does not make sense to me. I just tried InnoDB instead od MyISAM, but the generated statements still are the same: Only the owner is inserted.

Comment: After changing the storage engine (in both owners and cars table) maybe try clearing the cache as suggested by Dezigo. Last question: did you set any validation rule in your Car model?

Comment: Yes, according to PhpMyAdmin both are now InnoDB tables. Deleting the cache folder did not cause any changes. There are no validation rules for none of my tables.

Comment: maybe try to post more code

Comment: The other strange thing is that cake doesn't fill 'created' and 'updated' fields? Why? Do you have any behavior attached to your model?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's not possible to give a directly-working answer because: There's nothing wrong with the code in the question. That probably means you aren't running your own code at all.

Given that the only answer that can be given is advice, the only class that matters for the example in the question is `Owner`.

### Check filenames

The [model conventions](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/getting-started/cakephp-conventions.html#file-and-class-name-conventions) are:

> The Model class OptionValue would be found in a file named OptionValue.php

Misnamed model files is by far the most common cause of "why is my model logic not being executed" questions. One pitfall is to add the suffix `Model.php` to model files, is the model file named correctly?

In this case check that the file `app/Model/Owner.php` exists.

### Verify that the model is *your* model

If you're sure the model file is named correctly *check what the app is using*:

```
debug(get_class($this->Owner));
########## DEBUG ##########
'Owner'
###########################
```

If the output is "AppModel" - the model file is not loaded. There are very few reasons why CakePHP will not use a file that exists and one of them will apply:

- The file does not exist - there is a typo in the name
- The application is not looking in the same directory you are
- The application doesn't have permission to open the file

### Verify the association exists

```
debug($this->Owner->hasMany);
########## DEBUG ##########
array(
'Car' => array(
    'className' => 'Car',
    'foreignKey' => 'owner_id',
    'conditions' => '',
    'fields' => '',
    'order' => '',
    'limit' => '',
    'offset' => '',
    'dependent' => '',
    'exclusive' => '',
    'finderQuery' => '',
    'counterQuery' => ''
)
)
###########################
```

If `Car` is not in the output - the association isn't saved because to cake it doesn't exist - you'll need to identify why.

### Check which files are loaded

If in doubt, check which files are loaded at run time:

```
debug(get_included_files());
########## DEBUG ##########
array(
    ...
    ...app/Model/Owner.php
    ...
)
###########################
```

This may indicate that a *different* file is being loaded, which prevents `app/Model/Owner.php` from being loaded.

### Use a test to verify what's happening

You can use a test case to aide debugging for example:

```
<?php
App::uses('Owner', 'Model');

class OwnerTest extends CakeTestCase {

    public $fixtures = array(
        'app.car',
        'app.owner',
    );

    public function setUp() {
        parent::setUp();
        $this->Owner = ClassRegistry::init('Owner');
    }

    public function tearDown() {
        unset($this->Owner);
        parent::tearDown();
    }

    public function testCreate() {
        $data = array(
            'Owner' => array(
                'name' => 'Me'
            ),
            'Car' => array(
                array(
                    'Car' => array(
                        'color' => 'red',
                    )
                ),
                array(
                    'color' => 'blue',
                )
            )
        );

        $this->assertSame('Owner', get_class($this->Owner));

        $this->Owner->getDatasource()->getLog();
        $this->Owner->saveAssociated($data);
        $log = $this->Owner->getDatasource()->getLog();
        $expected = array();
        $this->assertSame($expected, $log, 'Look ma, the sql log');
    }
}
```

Which *should* output:

```
-> Console/cake test Test/Case/Model/OwnerTest.php 

Welcome to CakePHP v2.4.5 Console
---------------------------------------------------------------
App : app
Path: /var/www/files.dev/htdocs/app/
---------------------------------------------------------------
CakePHP Test Shell
---------------------------------------------------------------
PHPUnit 3.7.24 by Sebastian Bergmann.

F

Time: 169 ms, Memory: 9.00Mb

There was 1 failure:

1) OwnerTest::testCreate
Look ma, the sql log
Failed asserting that Array (
    'log' => Array (
        0 => Array (
            'query' => 'BEGIN'
            'params' => Array ()
            'affected' => null
            'numRows' => null
            'took' => null
        )
        1 => Array (
            'query' => 'INSERT INTO `test_database_name`.`owners` (`name`) VALUES ('Me')'
            'params' => Array ()
            'affected' => 1
            'numRows' => 1
            'took' => 0.0
        )
        2 => Array (
            'query' => 'INSERT INTO `test_database_name`.`cars` (`color`, `owner_id`) VALUES ('red', 1)'
            'params' => Array ()
            'affected' => 1
            'numRows' => 1
            'took' => 0.0
        )
        3 => Array (
            'query' => 'INSERT INTO `test_database_name`.`cars` (`color`, `owner_id`) VALUES ('blue', 1)'
            'params' => Array ()
            'affected' => 1
            'numRows' => 1
            'took' => 0.0
        )
        4 => Array (
            'query' => 'COMMIT'
            'params' => Array ()
            'affected' => 1
            'numRows' => 1
            'took' => 0.0
        )
    )
    'count' => 9
    'time' => 0.0
) is identical to Array ().

FAILURES!
Tests: 1, Assertions: 2, Failures: 1.
$
```

Note that correctly one owner was created for "Me", and two cars - each linked to the owner record for "Me".

Comment: You guessed it right! My Files were called OwnerModel.php and CarModel.php, because I thought the convention obliged this. After renaming them every thing works as expected. I don't even need the rest of your debugging tipps, but I will consider them the next time, when I face these kind of problems without any error message. Thank you so much!

Comment: Great reply!

If you are in a plugin, you might need to include PluginName when calling an association. For example I had $hasMany in Course.php model. Here in the $hasMany call I have to mention PluginName suffixing with period (.) for make it look like

'className' => 'Training.CoursesMembership'

If I do so it loads the  CoursesMembership model otherwise it wont.

Answer (score 3):

I'v tested your code.
It works perfect.
Try to remove models cache in **/tmp/cache** folder

My results:

```
(default) 3 queries took 0 ms   Nr  Query   Error   Affected    Num. rows   Took (ms)
1   BEGIN       0   0   0
2   INSERT INTO `intranet`.`owners` (`name`) VALUES ('Me')      1   1   0
3   INSERT INTO `intranet`.`cars` (`owner_id`, `color`) VALUES (3, 'red')       1   1   0
4   INSERT INTO `intranet`.`cars` (`owner_id`, `color`) VALUES (3, 'blue')      1   1   0
5   COMMIT      1   1   0
```

Comment: Thanks for your efforts! I've checked again if my app differs from the code which I posted above, but it's the same. Any ideas, where else I could look for the error cause?

Comment: Is debug mode enabled? Configure::write('debug', 2);

Comment: That didn't help either. :( Still looking for the cause. Could it be that I did not configure the database schema correctly?

Comment: I don't think so, I remember I had the same problem. Try to clear cache in cakephp, simply turn on and off the debug level in your config/core.php  and try to remove all files in /app/tmp/cache folder.

Comment: That's what I'm doing for two days now - yet without any outcome. :D I even tested it with CakePHP V 2.4.3, but nothing helped. Thank you anyway for all your help!

Answer (score 1):

Can you please try this:

```
$this->Owner->saveAll($data);
```

Instead of

```
$this->Owner->saveAssociated($data, array('deep' => true));
```

Thanks

Comment: Thanks for your idea, but this did not do any changes.

Comment: Yes, but this produces the same query as mentioned above. I'm trying everything to get this to work.

Comment: saveAll and saveAssociated are basically aliases - you're not suggesting anything different here.

Answer (score 0):

Not an actual answer but I've just tested your code and it works for me as well. (Cake 2.4.5)

```
(default) 5 queries took 2 ms
Nr  Query   Error   Affected    Num. rows   Took (ms)
1   BEGIN       0   0   0
2   INSERT INTO `cake_test_2`.`owners` (`name`, `updated`, `created`) VALUES ('Me', '2014-02-24 00:57:11', '2014-02-24 00:57:11')       1   1   0
3   INSERT INTO `cake_test_2`.`cars` (`owner_id`, `color`) VALUES (1, 'red')        1   1   0
4   INSERT INTO `cake_test_2`.`cars` (`owner_id`, `color`) VALUES (1, 'blue')       1   1   1
5   COMMIT      1   1   1
```

If you try with a fresh instance of CakePHP only with these necessary models and controller is it still not working?

Comment: As mentioned in the comments for Dezigos answer - I already tried this. What other framework conditions could cause the reason why it doesn't work for me?

Answer (score 0):

Note : For transactions to work correctly in MySQL your tables must use InnoDB engine. Remember that MyISAM tables do not support transactions.