# CakePHP $belongsTo not working

Tags: php, database, cakephp, controller, belongs-to

I am having a hell of a time getting my association to work here. every time I run the view action on the Events controller, and use var_dump, I just get back the event info, and no company info, it's like its ignoring my association all together, and whats even more annoying is there is no error messages.

the Events table has a field called Company_ID, and the Companies table has an ID field. (yes upper case Company_ID, and ID).

```
class Event extends AppModel{
    public $name = "Events";
//    public $belongsTo = 'Company';
    public $belongsTo = array('Company'=>array(
        'className' => 'Company',
        'foreignKey'=>'Company_ID'
    ));
    //public $hasOne = 'Company';
    /*public $hasOne = array('Company'=>array(
        'className' => 'Company',
        'foreignKey'=>'Company_ID'
    ));*/
}

App::uses("AppModel", "Model");
class Company extends AppModel{
    public $name = "Company";
}
```

The calling controller.

```
public function view() {
    $id = $this->request->params['id'];
    $this->set(
        'event', 
        $this->Event->find(
            'first', 
             array('conditions' => array('Event.id' => $id))
        )
    );
}
```

Comment: you have to tell cake that your primary key in Company is ID and not id: `public $primaryKey = 'ID';`

Comment: possible duplicate of [CakePHP does not save associated Models](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21910150/cakephp-does-not-save-associated-models). see `This is by far the most common cause of "why is my model logic not being executed" questions.`.

Comment: @arilia just tried that, that didn't seem to have any effect, plus I don't think that as the controller seems to have no problems with a upper case 'ID' for the view action.       public function view() {
        $id = $this->request->params['id'];
        $this->set('event', $this->Event->find('first', 
                array('conditions' => array('Event.id' => $id))));
    }

Comment: @AD7six it was the file names, some of them where the plural form vs. singular. I changed Events.php to Event.php and Companies.php to Company.php that seemed to do the trick.

Comment: @NateGates sweet - please put that in an answer and accept it =).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

possible duplicate of CakePHP does not save associated Models. see This is by far the most common cause of "why is my model logic not being executed" questions.

It was the file names, some of them where the plural form vs. singular. I changed Events.php to Event.php and Companies.php to Company.php that seemed to do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try the following:

This may help you

```
 public $belongsTo = array('Company'=>array(
    'className' => 'Company',
    'foreignKey'=>'company_id'
));
```

Thanks