# belongsTo does not work in cakephp3

Tags: php, sql, cakephp, foreign-key-relationship

organizatinos has relationship many-one with organType

Tabel organizations

```
id   |  name  | organType_id

1    |  a     | 1

2    |  b     | 1

3    |  c     | 2

4    |  d     | 3
```

Table organType

```
id   |  name  

1    |  aa     

2    |  bb    

3    |  cc
```

i in organiztinos model use `belongsTo=>'organType'`

Model organizations

```
class organizationsTable extends table
{
    public function initialize(array $config)
    {
        $this->table('organizations');
        $this->primaryKey('id');

        $this->belongsTo('organType', [
           'foreignKey' => 'organType_id',            
        ]);

    }
}
```

Model organType

```
class organTypeTable extends table
{
    public function initialize(array $config)
    {    
        $this->table('organType');
        $this->primaryKey('id');
    }
}
```

Controller

```
$organization=TableRegistry::get('organizations');
$organization=$organization->find('all')->offset(0)->limit(30) ;  
debug($organization);
```

but in result return only organizations table i want organizations inner join with organ_type

bad result:

```
'sql' => 'SELECT organizations.id AS `organizations__id`, organizations.name AS `organizations__name`, organizations.organType_id AS `organizations__organType_id` FROM organizations organizations LIMIT 30 OFFSET 0',
```

i want this result:

```
 'sql' => 'SELECT organizations.id , organizations.name , organizations.organType_id FROM organizations inner join organType on organizations.organType_id=organType.id
```

Comment: Check this link:- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22139097/cakephp-belongsto-not-working

Comment: Then try to check Out that "belongsTo" syntax is correct or not. Also check the name of model classes. Also try to check that relationships made correctly at database level or not. Only these three problem can occur in your case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[book.cakephp.org](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/associations.html)

for select from foreign table in cakephp 3 muse used `contain(['organType'])`

```
$organization=$organization->find('all')->contain(['organType'])->offset(0)->limit(30) ;
```