# Cake PHP display field

Tags: cakephp

I have 4 tables named customers, calls, employees and companies. Customers belong to a company and an employee. Calls belong to a customer and an employee. At the moment in my call index file it shows the relevant customer name and employee name. I want to display, for a call the relevant customer name, the customers company name  they belong to and the employee name. I don't know how to display the relevant company name based on the customer. Can someone help? This is my code:

call/ index.ctp

```
<?php
$usertype=$this->SESSION->read('User.usertype');
?>
<div class="calls index">
    <h2><?php echo __('Call Details'); ?>   </h2>
    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
            <th><?php echo $this->Paginator->sort('id'); ?></th>
            <th><?php echo $this->Paginator->sort('Call Date'); ?></th>
            <th><?php echo $this->Paginator->sort('Call Time'); ?></th>
            <th><?php echo $this->Paginator->sort('Comments'); ?></th>
            <th><?php echo $this->Paginator->sort('Next Call Date'); ?></th>
            <th><?php echo $this->Paginator->sort('Customer Name'); ?></th>
            <th><?php echo $this->Paginator->sort('Employee Name'); ?></th>

            <th class="actions"><?php echo __(''); ?></th>
    </tr>
    <?php foreach ($calls as $call): ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo h($call['Call']['id']); ?>&nbsp;</td>
        <td><?php echo h($call['Call']['call_date']); ?>&nbsp;</td>
        <td><?php echo h($call['Call']['call_time']); ?>&nbsp;</td>
        <td><?php echo h($call['Call']['comments']); ?>&nbsp;</td>
        <td><?php echo h($call['Call']['next_call_date']); ?>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>
            <?php echo $this->Html->link($call['Customers']['customer_name'], array('controller' => 'customers', 'action' => 'view', $call['Customers']['id'])); ?>
        </td>
        <td>
            <?php echo $this->Html->link($call['Employees']['employee_name'], array('controller' => 'employees', 'action' => 'view', $call['Employees']['id'])); ?>
        </td>

        <td class="actions">


            <?php echo $this->Html->link(__('View'), array('action' => 'view', $call['Call']['id'])); ?>
            </td>
    </tr>
```

callsController:

```
class CallsController extends AppController {

/**
 * Components
 *
 * @var array
 */
    public $components = array('Paginator');


/**
 * index method
 *
 * @return void
 */
    public function index() {
        $this->Call->recursive = 0;
        $this->set('calls', $this->Paginator->paginate());
    }

/**
 * view method
 *
 * @throws NotFoundException
 * @param string $id
 * @return void
 */
    public function view($id = null) {
        if (!$this->Call->exists($id)) {
            throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid call'));
        }
        $options = array('conditions' => array('Call.' . $this->Call->primaryKey => $id));
        $this->set('call', $this->Call->find('first', $options));
    }

/**
 * add method
 *
 * @return void
 */
    public function add() {
        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            $this->Call->create();
            if ($this->Call->save($this->request->data)) {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('The call has been saved.'));
                return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
            } else {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('The call could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
            }
        }
        $customers= $this->Call->Customers->find('list',array('order'=>'customer_name ASC','fields'=>array('id','customer_name')));
        $employees= $this->Call->Employees->find('list',array('order'=>'employee_name ASC','fields'=>array('id','employee_name')));
        $this->set(compact('customers', 'employees'));
    }

/**
 * edit method
 *
 * @throws NotFoundException
 * @param string $id
 * @return void
 */
    public function edit($id = null) {
        if (!$this->Call->exists($id)) {
            throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid call'));
        }
        if ($this->request->is(array('post', 'put'))) {
            if ($this->Call->save($this->request->data)) {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('The call has been saved.'));
                return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
            } else {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('The call could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
            }
        } else {
            $options = array('conditions' => array('Call.' . $this->Call->primaryKey => $id));
            $this->request->data = $this->Call->find('first', $options);
        }
        $customers= $this->Call->Customers->find('list',array('order'=>'customer_name ASC','fields'=>array('id','customer_name')));
        $employees= $this->Call->Employees->find('list',array('order'=>'employee_name ASC','fields'=>array('id','employee_name')));
        $this->set(compact('customers', 'employees'));
    }

/**
 * delete method
 *
 * @throws NotFoundException
 * @param string $id
 * @return void
 */
    public function delete($id = null) {
        $this->Call->id = $id;
        if (!$this->Call->exists()) {
            throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid call'));
        }
        $this->request->onlyAllow('post', 'delete');
        if ($this->Call->delete()) {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The call has been deleted.'));
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The call could not be deleted. Please, try again.'));
        }
        return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
    }}
```

the array looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [Call] => Array
        (
            [id] => 7
            [call_date] => 2013-04-27
            [call_time] => 08:31:00
            [comments] => Require installation
            [next_call_date] => 2014-04-27
            [customers_id] => 2
            [employees_id] => 3
        )

    [Customers] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [customer_name] => Snith Jams
            [customer_address] => 192 Waverley Road
            [customer_suburb] => Caulfield East
            [customer_state] => VIC
            [customer_postcode] => 3145
            [customer_dob] => 2014-04-09
            [customer_anniversary] => 2014-04-10
            [customer_phone1] => 0492832921
            [customer_phone2] => 0392817894
            [customer_phone3] => 0482938281
            [customer_fax] => 
            [customer_email] => tsmith@hotmail.com
            [customer_gender] => M
            [customer_type] => Silver
            [customer_PW] => a1c680c2bfcca40816dd81eff3980cc9828c9088
            [customer_username] => samman
            [companies_id] => 3
            [employees_id] => 11
        )

    [Employees] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [employee_name] => Jones
            [date_hired] => 2013-02-04
            [employee_phone_number] => 0449997582
            [employee_email] => indianajones@gmail.com
            [employee_address] => 22 Queens street Melbourne CBD
            [employee_dob] => 1966-01-31
            [access_level] => staff
            [employee_username] => jones12
            [employee_pw] => 603fce7dcbec3c9cba24e87d058a3341e37779b8
        )

)
```

callsController:

```
    public $components = array('Paginator');


        public function index() {
            $this->Call->recursive = 2;
            $this->set('calls', $this->Paginator->paginate());
        }
```

calls/index.ctp:

```
    <div class="calls index">
        <h2><?php echo __('Call Details'); ?>   </h2>


        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
        <tr>
                <th><?php echo $this->Paginator->sort('id'); ?></th>
                <th><?php echo $this->Paginator->sort('Call Date'); ?></th>
                <th><?php echo $this->Paginator->sort('Call Time'); ?></th>
                <th><?php echo $this->Paginator->sort('Comments'); ?></th>
                <th><?php echo $this->Paginator->sort('Next Call Date'); ?></th>
                <th><?php echo $this->Paginator->sort('Customer Name'); ?></th>
                <th><?php echo $this->Paginator->sort('Company Name'); ?></th>
                <th><?php echo $this->Paginator->sort('Employee Name'); ?></th>

                <th class="actions"><?php echo __(''); ?></th>
        </tr>

        <?php foreach ($calls as $call): ?>

        <tr>
            <td><?php echo h($call['Call']['id']); ?>&nbsp;</td>
            <td><?php echo h($call['Call']['call_date']); ?>&nbsp;</td>
            <td><?php echo h($call['Call']['call_time']); ?>&nbsp;</td>
            <td><?php echo h($call['Call']['comments']); ?>&nbsp;</td>
            <td><?php echo h($call['Call']['next_call_date']); ?>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>
                <?php echo $this->Html->link($call['Customers']['customer_name'], array('controller' => 'customers', 'action' => 'view', $call['Customers']['id'])); ?>
            </td>
            <td>
              <?php echo $this->Html->link($call['Customers']['Companies']['company_name']); ?>
              </td>
            <td>
                <?php echo $this->Html->link($call['Employees']['employee_name'], array('controller' => 'employees', 'action' => 'view', $call['Employees']['id'])); ?>
            </td>

      <?php echo pr($call); ?>

            <td class="actions">


                <?php echo $this->Html->link(__('View'), array('action' => 'view', $call['Call']['id'])); ?>
                </td>
        </tr>

    <?php endforeach; ?>

        </table>
```

Comment: `$this->SESSION` != `$this->Session` - You should pay attention to casing. It's an important thing in developing. Also: You should always mention the exact cakephp version you are using.

Answer (score 0):

just set recursive to 2

```
$this->Call->recursive = 2;
```

(or `$this->Calls->recursive = 2` it depends if your model is `Call` or `Calls`)

and you can access to Company information like this

```
$call['Customer']['Company']['name']
```

Because it seems you are not following cake naming conventions (you are using plural for Models' names) maybe you'll need to use

```
$call['Customers']['Companies']['name']
```

I suggest you to follow the conventions, anyway if you print your array doing `pr($call);` you'll see how the array is structured and how to access your data

Comment: I changed recursive to 2 and $call['Customers']['Companies]['name'], i get an error sayin Undefined index "companies" in line 69. This is the code now:

Comment: as suggested print your array so we can see the structure

Comment: if you set your relationships correctly and recursive to 2 then you should see the Company in your array. Post your models code (not all the code, just the part where you set the relationships)

Comment: calls model code:

public $belongsTo = array(
  'Customers' => array(
   'className' => 'Customers',
   'foreignKey' => 'customers_id',
   'conditions' => '',
   'fields' => '',
   'order' => ''

        ),

  'Employees' => array(
   'className' => 'Employees',
   'foreignKey' => 'employees_id',
   'conditions' => '',
   'fields' => '',
   'order' => ''
  )
 );

Comment: What model is it? I guess it's Calls. And what about Customers?

Comment: customers model:

public $belongsTo = array(
  'Companies' => array(
   'className' => 'Companies',
   'foreignKey' => 'companies_id',
   'conditions' => '',
   'fields' => '',
   'order' => ''
  ),
  'Employees' => array(
   'className' => 'Employees',
   'foreignKey' => 'employees_id',
   'conditions' => '',
   'fields' => '',
   'order' => ''
  )
 );

Comment: as long as your model name is `Calls` (and not `Call`) you have to write: `$this->Calls->recursive = 2;`. This is why it would be better if you followed the naming conventions

Comment: my model name is call and i changed recursive to $this->Call->recursive = 2, Is there any issue in my index.ctp code? I have updated the code above in the question

Comment: you wrote 'calls model' two comments above. Anyway the problem is in the controller or in the model. In fact the array is generated in the `index` action and as we can see it does not contain any information about. Consider using containable behavior, but at this point I can only suggest to read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21910150/cakephp-does-not-save-associated-models/21986180#21986180) answer that maybe could help you to find your problem