# cakePHP - SQL Query: parseCriteria

Tags: php, cakephp

I follow all steps described in: https://github.com/CakeDC/search/blob/master/Docs/Tutorials/Quick-Start.md but my search form dont work.

I'm received that message on load index page:

> Error: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You
>   have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to
>   your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near
>   'parseCriteria' at line 1
>
> SQL Query: parseCriteria

I searched several places, but found nothing that would help solve this.

```
class UsersController extends AppController {

    public $components = array(
        'Search.Prg'
    );

    public function index() {
        $this->Prg->commonProcess();
        $this->Paginator->settings['conditions'] = $this->User->parseCriteria($this->Prg->parsedParams());
        $this->set('users', $this->Paginator->paginate());
    }
}

class User extends AppModel {

    public $actsAs = array(
        'Search.Searchable'
    );

    public $filterArgs = array(
        'username' => array(
            'type' => 'like',
            'field' => 'username'
        ),
        'email' => array(
            'type' => 'like',
            'field' => 'email'
        ),
        'active' => array(
            'type' => 'value'
        )
    );

}

<!--index.ctp-->
    echo $this->Form->create();
    echo $this->Form->input('username');
    echo $this->Form->input('email');
    echo $this->Form->input('active', array(
        'type' => 'checkox'
    ));
    echo $this->Form->submit(__('Submit'));
    echo $this->Form->end();
```

Comment: Do you get other errors (i.e, the behavios is loaded?)? is your User Model files named `User.php`? check this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21910150/cakephp-does-not-seem-to-use-my-models/21986180#21986180): it has many suggestion to debug similar problems

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CakePHP does not use my models](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21910150/cakephp-does-not-seem-to-use-my-models).

Comment: Not duplicated. My test is created based on Tutorials Blog and Search Plugin and not works.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem. In the end I realized that in the controllers where the problem exists, I don't have correspondent models. So, most likely, the error lies in the model, not in the controller.