# How to join two tables using models in cakephp

Tags: cakephp

I just created 2 models UsersModel and UserpicsModel and try to get both records but it is returning Error: Call to a member function find() on a non-object.

```
//UsersModel.php 
class Users extends AppModel
{
     public $hasMany = array(
        'Userpics' => array(
            'className' => 'Userpics'
         )
    );

}   

//UserpicsMdoel.php
class Userpics extends AppModel
{
     public $belongsTo = array(
        'Users' => array(
            'className' => 'Users',
            'foreignKey' => 'uid'
         )
    );

}

//RecipesController.php
class RecipesController extends AppController {
    public $uses =array('Users','Userpics');
    public function view() {
        $users = $this->Users->Userpics->find('all');
        print('<pre>');
        print_r($users);
        print('<pre>');
        exit;
    }
 }
```

Comment: You should read the [Containable](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/containable.html#containable) section at the docs

Answer (score 0):

first: you are not following cake conventions: models should be singular and not plural.

But the actual problem here is that the model files names are wrong: if you still want to use your conventions then the name for the `Users` model should be `Users.php` and not `UsersModel.php`

the same for `Userpics`

read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21986180/2776508) useful answer about how to debug this kind of error.

But if you decide to use the cake naming conventions (and I strongly suggest you to do so)  consider doing the following:

```
//User.php (table users)
class User extends AppModel
{
    ....
}

//UserPic.php (table user_pics)
class UserPic extends AppModel
{
    ....
}

//RecipesController.php
class RecipesController extends AppController {
    public $uses =array('User','UserPic');
    public function view() {
        $users = $this->User->UserPic->find('all');
        print('<pre>');
        print_r($users);
        print('<pre>');
        exit;
    }
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
//UsersModel.php 
class Users extends AppModel

{
     public $hasMany = array(
        'Userpics' => array(
            'className' => 'Userpics',
            'foreignKey' => 'uid'
         )
    );

}
```