# find doesn't return associated model data cakePHP

Tags: cakephp, has-many, multiple-tables, model-associations, belongs-to

models Question and Answer

```
class Question extends AppModel {
    public $name = "Question";
    public $useTable = "questions";
    public $primaryKey = 'question_id';

    public $hasMany = array(
        'Answer' => array(
            'className' => 'Answer',
            'foreignKey' => 'question_id',
            'dependent' => true
        )
    );
}

class Answer extends AppModel {
    public $name = "Answer";
    public $useTable = "answers";
    public $primaryKey = 'answer_id'; 

    public $belongsTo = array(
        'Question' => array(
            'className' => 'Question',
            'foreignKey' => 'question_id',
         )
    );  
}
```

in database

answers
answer_id
question_id
text

questions
question_id
skill_id
text

in controller

$questions = $this->Question->find('all', array('conditions' => array('skill_id' => $skills)));

doesn't return me answers, it returns me only questions which matches skill id.

I want to fetch questions along with there answers in single find query.

Comment: check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/21986180/2776508 maybe it  helps

Comment: u dnt need to use `public $useTable = "questions";` as your table follows naming conventions. Use `public $recursive = -1;
`