# submit form data in database using cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp

I am using cakephp and I want to insert form data in my database, but I am getting the following error:

> Table posts for model Post was not found in datasource default.

How can I save my data to database. And in cakephp how can we send data from controller to model?

```
// this is my view code 

echo $this->Form->create('posts', array('action' => 'Add'));
echo $this->Form->input('title', array('label' => 'Enter your email address:'));
echo $this->Form->end('Add');


// this is my controller code

public function Add() {

    $this->request->data['posts']['title'] = $this->request->data["posts"]["title"]; 
    $this->Post->save($this->request->data);

}
```

Comment: Read the [tutorial](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/blog/part-two.html).

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/a/21986180/2776508

Answer (score -2):

Error says that model "Post" is not created. You need to create file PostsTable.php and put it in src/Model/Table folder.

Also just try CakePHP tutorial from CakeBook.

Comment: That's not what the error says. It says it's missing a database table to go with that model.