# Cakephp 3 - custom entity & table class not called?

Tags: php, cakephp, model, naming-conventions, cakephp-3.x

I am trying to implement my own class as an entity and table, but even if i do, it seems Cake still uses the default that it generates. How can i implement my own entity / table classes, and have Cake actually use them?

Here is the code i'm using in the controller:

```
$users = TableRegistry::get('Users');

    // If post, create user
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $newUser = $users->newEntity($this->request->data());
        $newUser->password = "tester";
        $result = $users->save($newUser);
    }
```

Then i have this entity class:

```
namespace App\Model\Entity;
use Cake\ORM\Entity;

class User extends Entity
{
    protected function _setPassword($value) {
        die('kage');
        $hasher = new DefaultPasswordHasher();
        return $hasher->hash($value);
    }
}
```

Even though i follow conventions, Cake still does not use this class and the _setPassword function is NEVER called? How do i make cake actually use this entity class?

Thanks

*** EDIT ***
I tried this:

```
$test = $users->newEntity();
    debug(get_class($test));
```

And that outputs:

```
'Cake\ORM\Entity'
```

Meaning that cake does NOT load in my model, for some weird reason i cannot figure out. i can manually create an instance using new User() and it fetches the right one, but i can't go through the table?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CakePHP does not use my models](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21910150/cakephp-does-not-use-my-models). This is for an older version of the framework - but it's the same problem/solution.

Comment: Thanks for the link, but so far it hasn't been able to help me further. I can verify it doesn't use the class, but why it doesn't i still don't know. The naming convention is correct.

Comment: `The naming convention is correct.` You haven't demonstrated that, there's no reason to think the duplicate is not your solution. There is further advice and information in the duplicate (please read the accepted answer).

Comment: Can you make sure the `password` is [accessible](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/entities.html#mass-assignment)?

Comment: Please see edit -> i just try to create a basic new entity, and it still doesn't use the class, so wether or not password is accessible is not the issue here.

Comment: You should really do what @AD7six said and check out the linked question, even if it's for 2.x. The model verification step is probably where you'll stumble over the source of the problem.