# cannot associate products and categories table in cakephp 3

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I have a table structure:

> products:

1. products_id
2. product_name
3. product_price
4. product_description
5. category_id

> categories:

1. category_id
2. category_name

There are 2 different forms to add and edit products and categories respectively. I want to associate both the tables so that i do not have to search category_name based on the category_id in the edit form dropdown list.
I have tried associating it but i got following errors:

> Table "Cake\ORM\Table" is not associated with "Categories"

```
class ProductsTable extends Table {
   public function initialize(array $config){
        $this->table('Products');
        $this->primaryKey('product_id');
       $this->belongsTo('Categories', ['foreignKey' => 'product_id']);

    }
}


class CategoriesTable extends Table {
  public function initialize(array $config){
     $this->table('Categories');
     $this->primaryKey('category_id');
      $this->hasMany('Products', ['foreignKey' => 'category_id']);
    }
}
```

View:

```
  public function index()
    {
$this->set('categories', $this->Products->Categories->find('list', array('fields' => array('Categories.category_id'),'value'=>array('Categories.category_name'))));
}
```

Please help to sort out my issue.

Comment: Check the type (`get_class`) of `$this->Products` in your index function. It seems that maybe it's not the type you expect it to be, but rather a generic table object. This might point to a file naming issue or a namespace problem.

Comment: @GregSchmidt: It prints Cake\ORM\Table.

Comment: Is the index method inside ProductsController? Check the files names and the folders. Maybe this answer is suitable for you too https://stackoverflow.com/a/21986180/2776508 (even if it was for cake 2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change 
$this->primaryKey('product_id');
to 
 $this->primaryKey('products_id');

And add
$this->displayField('category_name');